# Publishing maps using webhoster?

Tags: qgis, web-mapping, publishing, online-viewer

To publish my map projects I simply used qgis2web or QGIS Cloud but now I need more advanced features for more maps. Now I'm wondering, could the web space I've got from 'All-Inkl.de' be useful to setup a own Map Server?

> The specifications of my webspace: PHP 5.5 at Linux dd1120
>   3.13.0-96-generic #143-Ubuntu SMP x86_64 and Postgres without PostGIS

If not, what do I need to publish my maps online in a more advanced way? i.e. more display, layer and attribute options, the possibility to show the attribute table, editing attributes and downloading layers etc. QgisCloud Pro would be fine, but is still too expensive for me.